Issue with Antiforgery Token Decryption in .NET 8 Application Deployed Across Multiple Regions
I am currently developing a web application with a frontend built using Angular 12 and a backend consisting of three microservices developed using .NET 8 Web API. The database we are using is Azure SQL, and all microservices are deployed under a single Azure App Service plan. The frontend application is hosted in a separate azure appservice within the same app service plan. Both the frontend and backend APIs are secured using Microsoft Entra Id, requiring a Bearer token in the header for communication.
To ensure security against XSRF/CSRF attacks, I've implemented antiforgery tokens using .NET 8. However, during testing, I encountered an error related to the decryption of the antiforgery token.
The specific error message is:
"The antiforgery token could not be decrypted. The key {xxxxx-yyy-aaaa-bbb-ccccccc} was not found in the key ring."
This issue persists despite following standard implementation practices. Here are the resources I've referred to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0
https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1343/aspnet-core-csrf-antiforgery-token
Code:
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        StaticLogger.EnsureInitialized();
        Log.Information("Server Booting Up...");
        try
        {

            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            // Add XSRF protection services
            builder.Services.AddAntiforgeryServices();

            var app = builder.Build();
            app.UseAntiforgeryMiddleware();
            app.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (!ex.GetType().Name.Equals("StopTheHostException", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            StaticLogger.EnsureInitialized();
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Unhandled exception");
        }
        finally
        {
            StaticLogger.EnsureInitialized();
            Log.Information("Server Shutting down...");
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
}


public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the antiforgery services.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The services.</param>
    /// <returns>returns the antiforgery services.</returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddAntiforgeryServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var enableAntiforgeryToken = FeatureManagerService.IsFeatureEnabled(nameof(FeatureFlags.EnableAntiforgeryToken));

        if (enableAntiforgeryToken)
        {
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
            });

            /// Configuring ApplicationDiscriminator to set the same value across all the microservices to access the cookie for validating request.
            /// for reference:  https://github1s.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/DataProtectionOptions.cs
            services.Configure<DataProtectionOptions>(x => { x.ApplicationDiscriminator = Constants.AntiforgeryConstants.XXSRFTOKEN; });

            services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.HeaderName = Constants.AntiforgeryConstants.XXSRFTOKEN;
            });

            services.AddScoped<AntiforgeryMiddleware>();
        }

        return services;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses the antiforgery.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The application.</param>
    /// <returns>returns the antiforgery middleware.</returns>
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAntiforgeryMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var enableAntiforgery = FeatureManagerService.IsFeatureEnabled(nameof(FeatureFlags.EnableAntiforgeryToken));

        return app.UseIf(enableAntiforgery,
                x => x.UseMiddleware<AntiforgeryMiddleware>());
    }
}

Additional details:
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this decryption issue. Could there be a configuration step I might have missed, especially concerning the deployment across multiple regions?
Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What type of key are you using?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-8.0

You must configure the data protection API so that the same data protection key is used across each region and instance of the service. Otherwise, the key will often be regenerated after each deployment, which is why you see this error.
You don't need to add AddAntiforgeryServices explicitly in your application; it is added by the services that use it, like the Cookie authentication handler, Session middleware, OpenIDConnect....
There are many places where you can store this key, including:

See the Microsoft documentation for how to configure it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0
I have written a few blog posts related to the data protection API here:

Exploring what is inside the ASP.NET Core cookies
Introducing the Data Protection API Key Ring Debugger
Persisting the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault

